# Spring Lookup method injection not working

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-3

I am trying to achieve lookup method injection using a simple example. But, seems to fail in getting the bean injected via the method.

I have a simple bean namely; DemoBean as below:

```
public class DemoBean {

    private String message;

    public DemoBean() {

    }

    public DemoBean(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    // Getter and Setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DemoBean{" +
                "message='" + message + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject `DemoBean` into another bean namely; PropertyBean:

```
public abstract class PropertyBean {

    private DemoBean bean;
    private String message;
    // other members...

    public PropertyBean(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    // Getter and Setter methods...

    // Method for lookup injection
    protected abstract DemoBean createBean();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PropertyBean{" +
                "bean=" + bean.toString() +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", number=" + number +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Noe, there is my beans configuration:

```
<bean id="demobean" class="aro.discoverspring.beans.DemoBean" scope="prototype">
<property name="message" value="The Default Message!!!" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertybean" class="aro.discoverspring.beans.PropertyBean">
<constructor-arg name="message" value="A message in PropertyBean"/>
<lookup-method name="createBean" bean="demobean" />
</bean>
```

When try to create an instance of `PropertyBean`. I am able to do so. But when I do the following.. I get null pointer exception on the DemoBean property (Because the bean is not getting injected!!)

```
PropertyBean pb = (PropertyBean) ctx.getBean("propertybean");       
System.out.println(pb.toString());
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss anything or am I overlooking something silly there!?
[Spring 3.0 reference (section 3.4.6.1)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) seems to be doing the same.

Comment: In the Sping link the difference is that you put `scope="prototype"` in your `propertybean`. Try removing that

Comment: oops.. sorry! my mistake. I have corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bean` property shouldn't be injected. As I understand spring implements `createBean` method for you, so when you call `pb.createBean()` it should return instance of `DemoBean`. But you don't assign anything to `bean` property in `ProperyBean` so there is no way for it to be not null.

Comment: Have a look at spring reference (section 3.4.6 ) and specify section 3.4.6.1.. a similar example is show in reference too.. But I don't see any concept of `creatBean()` .. can you provide me any reference?

Comment: how do I do it without annotations?

Comment: @AbdelOlakara the example a bit different, because they actually use `createCommand` method. You may want to use lookup-method approach, when you don't want to pollute your class with `bean` property. When you need `DemoBean` in your class you just call `createBean`. Also `bean` won't be serialised in this case.

Comment: Ah a!! Now I get it.. Thanks!! Could you please remove the code in your answer.. it might mislead others.